# Removing white spaces between two strings

Tags: sql-server

I have the following string in a column:

```
<effect effrg="001003">              </effect>
```

I would like to remove the space between the two tags.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Is that the only mark up in there? Is this a one off? Old school way would be using CharIndex  and substring, but this is something you should fix at source, if at all...

Comment: you might use replace(replace(@data,'  ',' '),'  ',' ') in sql, that will replace each 2 spaces by one space and call this function twice to ensure that the result with come 1 space only

Answer (score 2):

I think it helps to you:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t
create table #t (x xml)
insert into #t(x)
values('<effect effrg="001003">              </effect>')

UPDATE #t
SET x.modify('replace value of 
(/effect/text())[1] with ("")')
```

You can also look an example [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stuff` function to remove the characters between the tags (by replacing with empty string), and using the `charindex` function twice to find the end of the first tag and the start of the second. 
The UPDATE statement becomes

```
update [table] set [colname] = stuff([colname], charindex('>',[colname],1)+1, charindex('</',[colname],1)-charindex('>',[colname],1)-1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a simple recursive query. the recursive query will reiterate through the text fields until no spaces are left.

```
;WITH data 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY [text]) RN 
         FROM   table1), 
     recurs 
     AS (SELECT Replace([text], ' ', '') [text], 
                rn 
         FROM   data 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Replace(T1.[text], ' ', '') [text], 
                T1.rn 
         FROM   recurs T1 
                INNER JOIN data T2 
                        ON T1.rn = T2.rn 
                           AND Charindex(T1.[text], ' ') > 0) 
SELECT * 
FROM   recurs
```

You can find a working example on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc726/1)</kbd>.

**Edited**

In order to preserve the spaces within the brackets a small change needs to be added (total of 4 characters added):

```
;WITH data 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY [text]) RN 
         FROM   table1), 
     recurs 
     AS (SELECT Replace([text], '> ', '>') [text], 
                rn 
         FROM   data 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Replace(T1.[text], '> ', '>') [text], 
                T1.rn 
         FROM   recurs T1 
                INNER JOIN data T2 
                        ON T1.rn = T2.rn 
                           AND Charindex(T1.[text], ' ') > 0) 
SELECT * 
FROM   recurs
```

You can find a working example for this version on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc726/2)</kbd> as well.

Comment: unfortunately this removes the space within the opening tag as well as the spaces between the tags.

Comment: @DeanOC, thanks for the comment. I've fixed the solution to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this cool trick:

```
Declare @s nvarchar(100) = '<effect effrg="001003">              </effect>'

Select replace(replace(replace(replace(@s, ' ', '[]'), '][', ''), '>[]<', '><'), '[]', ' ')
```

Output:

```
<effect effrg="001003"></effect>
```